# The wc -l gives wrong result

Tags: bash, wc

I got wrong result from the `wc -l` command. After a long :( checking a found the core of the problem, here is the simulation:

```
$ echo "line with end" > file
$ echo -n "line without end" >>file
$ wc -l file
       1 file
```

here are two lines, but missing the last "\n". Any easy solution?

Comment: any reason for using `echo -n` and why you can not add `\n` at the end of `echo -n`?

Comment: The above is an **SIMULATION** of the problem. I don't make the files, only working with them. I got them without the last enter.

Comment: Don't use a screwdriver to drive in nails when there's a hammer in your toolkit :-) You may _think_ that's two lines but the doco for `wc` disagrees.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

For the `wc` line is what ends with the "\n" char.  One of solutions is grep-ing the lines. The grep not looking for the ending NL.

e.g.

```
$ grep -c . file        #count the occurrence of any character
2
```

the above will not count empty lines. If you want them, use the

```
$ grep -c '^' file      #count the beginnings of the lines
2
```

Answer (score 18):

from man page of `wc`

```
 -l, --lines
              print the newline counts
```

form man page of `echo`

```
 -n     do not output the trailing newline
```

so you have `1` `newline` in your file and thus `wc -l` shows `1`.

You can use the following `awk` command to count lines

```
 awk 'END{print NR}' file
```